# How to make recyclerview layout manager like stack view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I want to introduce `RecyclerView` items like on photo below. Items overlap on each other on the top and every item have different margin from top which depends on vertical position on screen. How can I do it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this librabry and customize by as per your requirement

https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView

Answer (score -1):

Try using the fragments via viewPager. For example visit [viewpager-to-navigate](http://www.jamesmccann.nz/2014/10/20/android-using-viewpager-to-navigate-and-flip-a-set-of-cards.html) or [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480847/flip-a-view-in-viewpager) or [Transitions using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335461/switch-fragments-in-view-pager-with-flip-animation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Did you see photo via link in my question post? I want to create layout manager which can listen top value of every item and depends on it make overlapping value more or less. Please, help =)

Comment: Yes it will, go with the tutorials on viewpager. Modify the way you want to achieve.

Comment: For me very importnat use recyclerview. I attach link for video [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16rcnAS7MyftrzwqJ0TF1bXqzZ8hrypPK/view?usp=sharing) Please, help.

Comment: Sasha, viewPager will be perfect if the cards are limited as in video. For coding you should follow some tutorials available on net.